# c# dll to use in blender

Tags: c#, .net, blender

I want to create a DLL in C# that I will later import in a Blender Python Export script.

Never created a DLL before.
I created a simple project (Class Library .NET standard). I only need the basic types, and a 3dVector class that allows me to do basic operations with Vectors (+,-, dot and cross).

I tried to use System.Windows.Media.Media3D (to be able to use Vector3d), imported PresentationCore.dll, but then everytime I was using Vector3d I got:

> Error CS0012  The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

If I add mscorlib.dll then I get further errors.

Is there an easy way to setup a project in C# to create a dll and have a basic vector3d class?

Thanks!

Comment: `If I add mscorlib.dll then I get further errors` - what errors? You've made a post about a problem you've already solved rather than the problem you currently have.

Comment: A bunch: "Error CS0518 Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported" with System.Object, System.Single... My question is if there is an easy way to set up a DLL project and use a basic vector3d class

Comment: That error would suggest you've referenced the wrong `mscorlib.dll`. How did you add it and where from?

Answer (score 0):

> I created a simple project (Class Library .NET standard).

[.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) is for **portable libraries**. This means you won't be able to use any native Windows functionality such as graphics in a .NET Standard class library.

If you look on [apisof.net](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D), you can see that the type `System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D` is only supported on .NET Framework, not on .NET Standard.

So, to make this work you need to create a ***Class Library targeting .NET Framework*** instead of .NET Standard.